# How to parse sqare brackets in a web api post body?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I am configuring an asp.net web api to respond to a webhook.  The webhook sends its data in x-www-form-urlencoded format.  Some of the key names include square brackets [ ] which is causing my problem.

When my api receives a post from the webhook, the following key-value pair will appear as null:

> "data[reclaimed]":"123"

because the square brackets prevent proper parsing.  Are there any attributes or tools included with asp.net core that will allow me to parse square brackets?

Comment: 1. The `"data[reclaimed]":"123"` is not a valid `x-www-form-urlencoded` format . Are you saying that the webhook posts `data[reclaimed]=123&data[otherKye]=456` ?  2. You'd better show us your action method and the model  .

Comment: Well I`m trying to parse MailChrimp's webhook payload which is has the following structure:
 "type": "unsubscribe", 
"fired_at": "2009-03-26 21:40:57",  
"data[action]": "unsub",
"data[reason]": "manual", etc

Info on their webhook payload is here:
http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/about-webhooks/

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works for my requirements:

```
public void Post([FromBody] FormDataCollection data)
```

Inside the body of my Post method, I use data.Get("key_val") to extract all elements of the incoming payload.  For example:

```
string listId = data.Get("data[list_id]");
```

allows me to access the list_id element, etc.